# How to fix 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ' error in laravel from's select

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm setting up a Dynamic Dependant Select Box using laravel form's select but im keep getting that error

My index function

```
public function index()
{
    $compagnies = Compagnie::all()- 
>pluck("libelle_compagnie","id_compagnie")->toArray();
  return view('pages.quittances')->with('compagnies',$compagnies);
}
```

The result of $compagnies in tinker

```
[
     1 => "AXA assurance",
     2 => "AXA assistance",
     3 => "MAROC assistance",
   ]
```

My select tag

```
{{ Form::select('compagnies',[''=>'Select compagnies']+$compagnies,null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}
```

error pic
[image]

My table in DB

[image: e]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function index()
 {
    $compagnies = Compagnie::all()->pluck("libelle_compagnie","id_compagnie");
    return view('pages.quittances')->with('compagnies',$compagnies);
 }
```

just remove toArray() from Compagnie::all()->pluck("libelle_compagnie","id_compagnie") because pluck() will convert object into array automatically.

read
  [1]: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck for more details.

Comment: now im getting Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int

Comment: please share your table

Comment: i did check the post

Comment: first try to dd($compagnies) are you getting data in that or not?

Comment: sry i didn't understand

Comment: $compagnies = Compagnie::all()->pluck("libelle_compagnie","id_compagnie"); dd($compagnies);   do this

Comment: its return this

Collection {#1127 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    1 => "AXA assurance"
    2 => "AXA assistance"
    3 => "MAROC assistance"
  ]
}